# AngularJS PUT vs Symfony2 PUT method. Update doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I'm building app in symfony2.4 and angularjs. In angular I've created resource:

```
app.factory('Tasks', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource( 'api/tasks/:taskid', null,
         {
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
}]);
```

and when I'm trying to update like this: `Tasks.update({ taskid : task.id },task);`I'm getting this error:

```
{"code":400,"message":"Validation Failed","errors":{"errors":["The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."],"children":{"timeStart":{"children":{"date":[],"time":[]}},"timeStop":{"children":{"date":[],"time":[]}},"project":[],"descriptionTask":[],"isCompleted":[],"isVisible":[]}}}
```

**When I build form in symfony and then update any task - it works.** But I noticed that **AngularJS doesn't send any data via POST**. It sends via JSON(? or just sends this object I'm giving ) and I think this is the problem. How can I repair it?

Comment: You're missing the CSRF (anti forgery) token.

Comment: and how to add it? :) as a task property?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add the `_token` in your form i.e
>
> ```
> {{ form_row(form._token) }}
> ```
>
> As of now your form is missing with the csrf token field,if you use the twig form functions to render your form like `form(form)` this will automatically renders the csrf token field for you but your code show your are rendering your form with raw html for form like `<form></form>` then you have to manually render the field
>
> or simply add `{{ form_rest(form) }}` before closing tag of form
>
> According to docs
>
> This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given
> form. It's a good idea to always have this somewhere inside your form
> as it'll render hidden fields for you and make any fields you forgot
> to render more obvious (since it'll render the field for you).
>
> [**form_rest(view, variables)**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables)

Answer from @M Khalid Junaid in  [The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455780/the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form)